# Yesod/Persistent testing with bracket pattern

Tags: testing, haskell, entity, persistent, yesod

I'm very new to Haskell, so I'm having trouble absorbing all of the advanced features used in Yesod such as [type instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Instance_declarations_2) and [equality constraints](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_families#Equality_constraints). I am trying to implement the [bracket pattern](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bracket_pattern) in Yesod's test framework in order to get setUp/tearDown functionality. Here's what I've got so far (updated via edit):

```
module FishMother where

import Control.Exception.Lifted

import TestImport
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.GenericSql

import Model

insertYellowfinTuna :: OneSpec Connection FishId
insertYellowfinTuna = runDB . insert $ Fish "Yellowfin Tuna"

deleteFish :: FishId -> OneSpec Connection ()
deleteFish = runDB . delete

withYellowfinTuna :: FishId -> OneSpec Connection ()
withYellowfinTuna = bracket insertYellowfinTuna deleteFish
```

The compile errors are as follows:

```
tests/FishMother.hs:18:21:
    Couldn't match type `FishId
             -> Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                  (Yesod.Test.OneSpecData Connection) IO ()'
          with `Key SqlPersist Fish'
    Expected type: FishId -> OneSpec Connection ()
      Actual type: (FishId
            -> Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
             (Yesod.Test.OneSpecData Connection) IO ())
           -> Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
            (Yesod.Test.OneSpecData Connection) IO ()
    In the return type of a call of `bracket'
    In the expression: bracket insertYellowfinTuna deleteFish
    In an equation for `withYellowfinTuna':
    withYellowfinTuna = bracket insertYellowfinTuna deleteFish
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forget entirely about Yesod for the moment. If this was just normal `IO`, you'd have functions `setup :: IO FishId`, `tearDown :: FishId -> IO ()`, and then `withYellowfinTuna = bracket setup tearDown`. Play around with understanding what the type of that function would be first, and then come back to the Yesod world and try replacing `IO` with the `OneSpec Connection` monad.

Comment: Thanks @michael-snoyman. Sometimes you just need to take a step back or even get some sleep in order to solve a problem. It also helped to know I was on the right track with `OneSpec Connection` and the types of the other functions. Here's the corrected type signature I was looking for: `withYellowfinTuna :: (FishId -> OneSpec Connection ()) -> OneSpec Connection ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After rereading the question, I think the simple answer is to use [a lifted bracket](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lifted-base/0.2.0.2/doc/html/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v%3abracket), which will handle all of the transformer issues. I'll leave my original answer as well, as it might give a bit more insight into what's happening.

---

The problem in this case is the usage of `liftIO`. Let's look at the type signature:

```
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```

What this means is that you can take an arbitrary I/O action (e.g., reading from a file) and run it in any monad which allows I/O to be performed, such as the database monad. However, what you're trying to do is really the opposite: run a database monad action as just a normal I/O action. This can't be directly done, since the database actions rely on extra context- specifically a database connection- which the `IO` monad doesn't provide.

So how do you turn a database action into an IO action? We have to *unwrap*. Unwrapping is a common activity for *monad transformers*, which can be thought of as layers added on top of each other. Lifting (as in `liftIO`) allows you to take an action from a lower layer and move it up to a higher layer. Unwrapping takes a layer off. Since how you unwrap depends on the specific transformer, each transformer has its own unwrap functions.

In the case of Persistent, you can use withSqliteConn or the equivalent for your backend, see the synopsis in the [Persistent chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the clues. I removed the `liftIO` calls and am using the lifted `bracket`, but I'm still having trouble. I think one of the clues I need is the type signature of withYellowfinTuna. I know it's not supposed to be `FishId -> PersistMonadBackend ()`, but I can't figure out what it *is* supposed to be! I should probably also say that I'd rather mention I'd rather avoid using database-specific calls such as `withSqliteConn` whenever possible. Unfortunately, though, the relationship between `runDB`, `withSqliteConn`, and `runSqlConn` is not quite clear to me, yet.

Comment: I've updated my original post with where I ended up after reading your answer, but I am still stuck. I'm having trouble figuring this out, I think, because I don't know the type signatures of `insert` and `delete` in the context of my `Fish` model. Also, is it actually appropriate for me to call `runDB` in these places, and why? I don't know why my return type is `OneSpec Connection ()` after calling `runDB`, but it's what the compile errors told me to use!